# Can canonical URL redirect to equivalent user-friendly URL without hurting SEO?

Tags: url, redirect, seo, google-search, canonical-link

I'm developing a "article gallery" website system. The articles have assigned a canonical name, but their path (what folder they are in) and name can change.

If you visit a url that ends with the canonical name, you're redirected to the right path where the article currently is. Internally, I use this for stable links between articles, so they work even if the article has moved or renamed.

Examples:

```
example.com/blah/blah/140913-china
example.com/140913-china
```

Both redirect to:

```
example.com/journeys/asia/visit-to-china
```

If I move the article, the former urls will still work - for this new path:

```
example.com/my-adventures/china
```

That works fine, but I want Google to preserve the pagerank and other things associated with the article, even if it has moved to a different path.

For that purpose, I'd add this to the article page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="example.com/140913-china">
```

That url will *always* work and redirect to the article.

But, will Google allow this - redirect on canonical url? If not, how else can I do it?

My only requirement is that the user gets the actual full article path in the url bar - which is needed to properly fetch article-relative resources etc.

Answer (score 0):

**NO!** I don't understand why you redirect the canonical link (or use user-friendly link as canonical), and don't show the content for this page...
Even if to do so, you have to internaly redirect...

Remark: Avoid errors: use absolute paths rather than relative paths with the rel="canonical" link element. -> [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

Comment: Well, it's for technical reasons. My articles are stored in a real folder structure, and so relative urls from within the article are correctly routed to the resources that belong to the article (actually, this goes through php script that serves the files, but that's implementation detail). If I let people stay on the canonical address, the links will not work (I'd have to do some crazy resolver function to deal with that).

Comment: Don't forget to use absolute paths in your canonical link, because with directory redirections...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is yes, but it is not optimal and not 100% guaranteed. Canonical links are recommendations, not obligations to Google. It may decide to index another URL for that page.

It is always a good practice to have the canonical link always point to the definitive location of the article (without an extra redirect). You will loose less link juice (i.e. PageRank).

But, the way you describe your issue, it does not seem like you need canonical links, since you say all your redirects work properly. If you move your content again, modify the redirects to target the correct new location. It is enough.

In the comment to Croises' answers about 'canonical addresses not working', you should use relative paths instead of absolute paths. In other words, remove the domain name and begin urls with a leading '/' (in other words, [make your site portable](https://ligatures.net/content/expertise/seo-miscellaneous-questions-faq.html#PORTABLE_WS)).

For example:

```
example.com/140913-china -- Absolute path (includes domain name)
/140913-china            -- Relative path (i.e., relative to the root of your site)
```

That will avoid a lot of pain when migrating your content.